# Receiving a dimension error for the cross product of two arrays in python

Tags: python, numpy, dimensions, cross-product

I am having an issue with doing the cross product of two arrays in this code which is supposed to calculate the attitude determination algorithm for a satellite.

Here is the code:

```
rom os import confstr_names
from pickleshare import print_function
import math
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=15, suppress=True)
h = 422.0;
Lat = 48.5;
Long = -110.4;
Y = 2022;
M = 10;
D = 18;
hr = 11;
m = 50;
s = 2;
psi = 0;
theta = -90;
phi = 0;
TargetLat = 50.8;
TargetLong = -105.4;
Rearth = 6378.137; 
Lat_rads = math.radians(Lat)
Long_rads = math.radians(Long)
psi_rads = math.radians(psi)
theta_rads = math.radians(theta)
phi_rads = math.radians(phi)
x = (Rearth + h) * math.cos(Lat_rads) * math.cos(Long_rads) 
y = (Rearth + h) * math.cos(Lat_rads) * math.sin(Long_rads)
z = (Rearth + h) * math.sin(Lat_rads)
r = math.sqrt((x**2)+(y**2)+(z**2))

def Magnetic_field(x,y,z,r):
  g1 = -1669.05
  h1 = 5077.99
  g0 = -29554.63
  a = 6371.2
  mx = (a**3)*g1
  my = (a**3)*h1
  mz = (a**3)*g0
  Bx = (3*((mx*x) + (my*y) + (mz*z))*x - (r**2)*(mx))/(r**5)
  By = (3*((mx*x) + (my*y) + (mz*z))*y - (r**2)*(my))/(r**5)
  Bz = (3*((mx*x) + (my*y) + (mz*z))*z - (r**2)*(mz))/(r**5)
  B1 = math.sqrt((Bx**2) + (By**2) + (Bz**2))
  B2 = np.array([[Bx], [By], [Bz]])
  return B2;
B2 = Magnetic_field(x,y,z,r)
print("B = ",B2)

def Sun_Position(Y, M, D, hr, m, s, x, y, z):
  b1 = (7/4) * (Y+1)
  b2 = round(b1)
  c1 = (275 * M)/9
  c2 = round(c1)
  Au = 149597870.691
  JD = 1721013.5 + 367*Y - b2 + c2 + D + (60*hr+m+s/60)/1440;
  Tu = (JD-2451545)/36525;
  Phi = 280.460 + 36000.771*Tu;
  Mo = 357.5277233 + 35999.05034*Tu;
  Phi_rads = math.radians(Phi)
  Mo_rads = math.radians(Mo)
  Phie = Phi + (1.914666471 * math.sin(Mo_rads)) + (0.019994643 * math.sin(2*Mo_rads))
  Epsilon = 23.439291 - 0.0120042*Tu
  Phie_rads = math.radians(Phie)
  Epsilon_rads = math.radians(Epsilon)
  eo = np.array([[(math.cos(Phie_rads))], [(math.cos(Epsilon_rads) * math.sin(Phie_rads))], [(math.sin(Epsilon_rads))*(math.sin(Phie_rads))]])
  r1 = 1.000140612 - 0.016708617 * math.cos(Mo_rads) - 0.000139589 * math.cos(2*Mo_rads);
  R1 = r1 * Au
  RA = R1 * eo
  RB1 = (RA[0])-x
  RC1 = (RA[1])-y
  RD1 = (RA[2])-z
  R2 = np.sqrt((RB1**2) + (RC1**2) + (RD1**2))
  e1 = RB1 / R2
  e2 = RC1 / R2
  e3 = RD1 / R2
  Sun = np.array([e1, e2, e3])
  return Sun;

Sun= Sun_Position(Y, M, D, hr, m, s, x, y, z)
print("Sun",Sun)

def Attitude_Matrix(psi_rads, theta_rads, phi_rads):
  A = np.array([[math.cos(theta_rads)*math.cos(phi_rads), math.cos(theta_rads)*math.sin(phi_rads), -math.sin(theta_rads)], [(-math.cos(psi_rads)*math.sin(phi_rads))+(math.sin(psi_rads)*math.sin(theta_rads)*math.cos(phi_rads)), (math.cos(psi_rads)*math.cos(phi_rads)) + (math.sin(psi_rads)*math.sin(theta_rads)*math.cos(phi_rads)), math.sin(psi_rads)*math.cos(theta_rads)], [(math.cos(psi_rads)*math.sin(theta_rads)*math.cos(phi_rads)) + (math.sin(psi_rads)*math.sin(phi_rads)), ((math.cos(psi_rads)*math.sin(theta_rads)*math.sin(phi_rads)) - (math.sin(psi_rads)*math.cos(phi_rads))), (math.cos(psi_rads)*math.cos(theta_rads))]])
  return A;
A = Attitude_Matrix(psi_rads, theta_rads, phi_rads)
print("Attitude Matrix = ",A)

r1 = B2/(np.linalg.norm(B2))
print("r1 = ",r1)
r2 = Sun/(np.linalg.norm(Sun))
print("r2 = ",r2)
b1 = A*r1.T
print("b1 = ",b1)
b1x = b1[0][-1] + ((0.2)*b1[0][-1]) 
b1y = b1[1][1] + ((0.1)*b1[1][1])
b1z = b1[2][0] + ((0.3)*b1[2][0]) 
b1error = [b1x, b1y, b1z]
print("b1error = ",b1error)
b2 = A*r2.T
print("b2 = ",b2)
b2x = b2[0][-1] + ((0.2)*b2[0][-1]) 
b2y = b2[1][1] + ((0.1)*b2[1][1])
b2z = b2[2][0] + ((0.3)*b2[2][0]) 
b2error = [b2x, b2y, b2z]
b1errornorm = b1error/(np.linalg.norm(b1error))
print("b1error normalized = ",b1errornorm)
b2errornorm = b2error/(np.linalg.norm(b2error))
print("b2error normalized = ",b2errornorm)
j1 = np.cross(b1errornorm , b2errornorm)
j1norm = j1/(np.linalg.norm(j1))
k = np.cross(b1errornorm,j1norm)
knorm = k/(np.linalg.norm(k))
L = np.array([b1errornorm, j1norm, knorm]).T
print("L = ",L)
r12 = np.array([r1]).T
r22= np.array([r2]).T
M = np.cross(r12, r22)
Mnorm = M/(np.linalg.norm(M))
print("Mnorm = ",Mnorm)
N = np.cross(r1 , M)
Nnorm = N/(np.linalg.norm(N))
O = np.array([[r1], [Mnorm], [Nnorm]]).T
TRIAD = L * O
```

The error message is given by this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-29ce1cf02cca> in <module>
    114 r12 = np.array([r1]).T
    115 r22= np.array([r2]).T
--> 116 M = np.cross(r12, r22)
    117 Mnorm = M/(np.linalg.norm(M))
    118 print("Mnorm = ",Mnorm)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py in cross(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in cross(a, b, axisa, axisb, axisc, axis)
   1605            "(dimension must be 2 or 3)")
   1606     if a.shape[-1] not in (2, 3) or b.shape[-1] not in (2, 3):
-> 1607         raise ValueError(msg)
   1608 
   1609     # Create the output array

ValueError: incompatible dimensions for cross product
(dimension must be 2 or 3)
```

I have tried to directly convert r1 and r2 into arrays but that causes a similar issue in the b1 and b2 portions of the code. I am expecting the cross product of r1 and r2 which are supposed to be arrays that are representative of matrices that are 1 column each.

Comment: What is `r12.shape` and `r22.shape`.  Don't make us deduce that; and don't guess yourself.  Show that actual shapes that `cross` will see.  As a bonus, compare those shapes with  the shape the `cross` says it expects.

Comment: Hello, r12.shape and r22.shape are both (1,3,1). I am still unsure how to proceed from here, thank you for your help

Comment: I have resolved the issue by reshaping the array. Thank you so much for your help, it is greatly appreciated.